# passing the value of an array to a method in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, servlets

I have to create an HTML table in which I will have images to display. further I want to pass this path to the next servlet page. for this I have created a separate method in javascript. Now the problem is this, whenever I click on any image it passes the same path everytime. please give me any solutions for this problem or tell me any alternate of passing the path to next page. 
my code is--->

```
<%@page import = "java.util.*" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <h3>${requestScope.payment}</h3>
            <jsp:include page="Header.jsp"/>
            <jsp:include page="Menu2.jsp"></jsp:include>
            <form method="post" action="ProductFeatures" id="myform">
                <table border="1" bordercolor="green" bgcolor="yellow" align="center" id="store" >
                </table>
            </form>
            <%
             ArrayList<String> l = null;
             if(request.getAttribute("list") instanceof ArrayList<?>){
                 l = (ArrayList<String>)request.getAttribute("list");
             }
             %>
             <script type="text/javascript">
             window.onload = function(){
                 var path = new Array();
                 var imagepath = new Array();
                 var table = document.getElementById("store");
                 var j=0;
                 var k=0;
                 var row = null;
                 <%for(int i=0;i<l.size();i++) {%>
                     path.push("<%=l.get(i)%>");
                 <%}%>
                 for(i=0;i<path.length;i++){
                     imagepath[i] =path[i].replace ("F:java_projectsApplication4images","F:\\java_projects\\Application4\\images\\");
                 }
                 for(i=0;i<path.length;i++){
                     if(i%4==0){
                         row = table.insertRow(j);
                         k=0;
                         j++;
                     }
                     var data = imagepath[i];
                     var cell = row.insertCell(k);
                     var image = document.createElement("img");
                     image.setAttribute("src",imagepath[i]);
                     image.setAttribute("height","160");
                     image.setAttribute("width","120");
                     image.setAttribute("onclick",function(){getDetails(data);});
                     cell.appendChild(image);
                     row.appendChild(cell);
                     k++;
                 }
             };

             function getDetails(imagepath){
                 document.write(imagepath);
                 if(path.length>10){
                     var form = document.getElementById("myform");
                     var input = document.createElement("input");
                     input.type="hidden";
                     input.value=imagepath;
                     input.name="imagepath";
                     form.appendChild(input);
                     form.submit();
                 }
             }
            </script>
            <jsp:include page="Footer.jsp"/>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here in this code in function getDetails variable imagepath always contains the same value. please somebody tell me wheres the bug in this code. I am not getting it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following line:

```
image.setAttribute("onclick",function(){getDetails(data);});
```

into:

```
image.setAttribute("onclick",(function(d){return function(){getDetails(d);}}(data));
```

Also, the line:

```
row.appendChild(cell);
```

is redondant because the cell was inserted with row.insertCell(k)